# adding search functionality to a paginated page in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the scenario:

I have a table which renders a list of groups (id,title,description,etc) like below which is paginated, it also has a search form:

```
<div id="navigation" style="background:white;border:1px outset cadetblue;">
<p>
  <% form_tag groups_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p> 
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]  %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   </p>
<% end %>
</p> 
</div>
<table>
.....
</table>
<%= paginate @groups %>
```

In my groups_controller.rb I have:

```
@groups = Group.search(params[:search])
@groups = Group.order("id").page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

which doesn't seem to be working. The pagination works but when I click 
the search button it doesn't do anything.
The search function is implemented in the group.rb model:

```
def self.search(search)
   if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['description LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
   else
    find(:all)
   end
end
```

How do I solve this, how do I make my search form work and return results in a paginated way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ultimate answer to this post.  All the original poster needed to do was this:

```
@groups = Group.where("description LIKE '%#{params[:search]}%'").order('id').page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

In an offline discussion, it wasn't working.  turns out he had BOTH will_paginate Gem and kaminari Gem for his pagination.  He was crapping out when it came to .per(15).  Deleting the will_paginate gem fixed it!

will_paginate isn't being actively upgraded,  so if you have will_paginate and you are on Rails 3.X,  get rid of will_paginate and use kaminari instead,  it's a fairly painless swap out,  just a bit of css work to format the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine those two calls into one,  right now you are overriding the first setting of @groups with the second.

I'd add a scope to your group model

```
class Group
  scope :search, lambda { |val| , find(:all, :conditions=>['description LIKE ?', "%#{val}%"]) }
end
```

Then you can do

```
@groups = Group.search(params[:search]).order("id").page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

Comment: I removed that comma after |val| as it was giving me an error but now it says "undefined method `order' "

Comment: removed order now and did it like this: @groups = Group.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per(15) but still not working, now it say 'undefined method 'page'

Comment: scope :search, lambda {|val| where("description LIKE ?","%#{val}%") }

Comment: still got the same error. I'm using ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0.11

Comment: If that works, depends on Rails version, you shouldn't even need the scope

@groups = Group.where("description LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%").order("id").page(params[:page]).per(15)

Comment: OK, that's the problem,  you're in the twilight zone with rails versions,  any chance you can upgrade?  I think if you can get beyond 3.1 the last comment should work.

Comment: that's the last thing i want to do... i'm already deep in my project...I've heard rails upgrades are pretty exhaustingly painful, surely there must be some other way to do this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9548/discussion-between-radbrad-and-bytebiscuit)